# Ordering of values in couchdb reduce

Tags: couchdb

Are the `values` in the CouchDB `reduce` function passed in order according to the `keys` argument?

I mean of course when the `rereduce` argument is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `keys` and `values` should have a 1:1 mapping, and in the same order. It's not explicitly stated in the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#reduce-and-rereduce-functions), but contextually that's what I gather.

Comment: It's not what I observed the order of the values passed to the reduced were different from the output of the map. Are you sure?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The `keys` and `values` arrays passed to the reduce function should be what line up. The output you see running the view with `reduce=false` may differ, but your reduce function should be pure in this regard. (ie: `keys[0]` goes with `values[0]` and so on)

Comment: do the output of the map function is the same as the input of the values for reduce function given certain `startkey` and `endkey`?